# Install Magento Base with Composer

Tags: magento-1, installation, composer

I know there are nice ways to install Magento Modules (from Connect) and from GitHub (if composer.json is provided).

(as described in http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/composer-with-magento/)

Is it possible also to install the basic Magento package (for example CE 1.7.0.2) using Composer?

Did anybody already try that? (if successfully or not)

Comment: Check out my new blogpost http://razbakov.com/blog/install-magento-via-composer/. We finally have firegento/magento repo and use it as frequently synced magento-mirror-repo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently it can only be installed using

`$ composer create-project "kylecannon/magento" -s dev`

The package of course could be replaced with any other trustworthy Magento package of your choice.

Of course that's not satisfactory, since it can't simply be installed by adding it as a requirement in the composer.json.

The `magento-composer-installer` project currently doesn't support installing `Mage_Core_Latest` due to missing dependencies. If nobody else fixes that in the http://packages.firegento.com build script, I want to do it at the next hackathon at the latest.

Comment: is there any GitHub issue for that?

Comment: Yes, but somehow I closed it: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer/issues/27 (just reopened)

Answer (score 7):

If you use the alternative [composer installers by AOE](https://github.com/AOEpeople/composer-installers), you can add a composer package of type `magento-source` as dependency and specify where the code should be placed:

```
"extra":{
    "installer-paths": {
        "www/" : [ "type:magento-source" ],
        ".modman/{$vendor}_{$name}/" : [ "type:magento-module" ]
    },
```

For the Magento core you will need a repository with a `composer.json` as follows:

```
{
    "name": "magento/ce",
    "description": "Magento Repository",
    "type": "magento-source",
    "require": {}
}
```

We use separate branches for each `1.x.x` version and apply patches on each branch. To be compatible with composer's version constraints, tags are added like this: `1.9.1.0-patch6285`

This strategy works well if you consequently use [`modman`](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman) to link any custom files into the Magento root directory and don't add files directly. Then you can decide if you want to add the whole `www` directory with the symlinks to Git or exclude it.

In the example above, the AOE installers are configured to put Magento modules directly into the `.modman` directory, so that you can create the symlinks with a single `modman deploy-all`. You can make use of composer scripts to trigger it automatically after `composer install` and `composer update`:

```
"scripts":{
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "modman deploy-all --force"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "modman deploy-all --force"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm working now on creating **ready-to-go** development package for magento.
It will include vagrant box with puppet configuration and magento as dependency in composer.

You can use my latest [Magento as Composer Dependency](https://medium.com/magento-development/magento-and-composer-44af0883abd9)

Comment: the link is sadly invalid, can you fix this?

Comment: updated, thank you

Answer (score -2):

I stumbled over this article: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/composer-with-magento/ — maybe it has the answer you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks, I know this article and edited my question to refer to it. I think it "only" covers installing modules - but not the Magento base installation.

Comment: Correct, only modules, not base Magento